# How to create a proxy in React/Webpack to call an external API

Tags: reactjs, webpack, proxy, create-react-app

I want to issue a GET request to an external API that I do not control. Because of the security on the API, my react app cannot directly make an ajax request to the endpoint. Therefore I'm trying to create a simple proxy as demonstrated [here](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#configuring-the-proxy-manually)

My `package.json file` looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "my-stack",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.13"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": {
    "https://gold-feed.com/paid/*": {
        "target": "https://gold-feed.com/paid",
        "changeOrigin": true
    }
  }
}
```

And then my ajax request looks like this:

```
const apiUrl = 'https://gold-feed.com/paid/<apiID>/all_metals_json_usd.php';

jQuery.ajax({
  method: 'GET',
  url: apiUrl,
  success: (item) => {
    this.props.addItem(item);
  }
});
```

But it doesn't appear to be doing anything. I'm still getting the following error:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I essentially have the same issue as documented [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/4xury9/react_webpack_and_api_calls/) where he is trying to create a proxy to access the Steam api.

And just a side note, I believe the create-react-app project that I'm using is piggybacking off of webpack.

Comment: Very interesting your question, I'm not an expert in React, but, it seems that as without proxy config, the browser is doing the request and of course, the CORS policies are applied. The way to accomplish by myself should be, exposing a Rest API in node and is the backend the requester to the api, and my frontend only communicates with my backend so front doesn't care about CORS problems with third party apis. Using axios in react/redux architecture maybe solve the problem, but i'm no pretty sure

Comment: I've had to the same problem but I fixed it by simply doing ```"proxy": 
    "https://gold-feed.com/paid/" }```. Can you give a try like that?

Comment: I'll try that. You put it in package.json?

Comment: In case you are using webpack-dev-server try `devServer: {
        proxy: {
            'https://gold-feed.com/': {
                target: 'https://gold-feed.com/',
                secure: false
            }
        }
    }` inside webpack.config.js.

Comment: @Matthew Barbara Unfortunately that's not working for me. Did you have to change anything else other than that line in package.json? Did you have to reference the proxy anywhere else? Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You probably figured it out by now but for others here is what worked for 
me:

```
"proxy": {
    "/proxy": {
        "target": "https://mybackend.com",
        "pathRewrite": {
                "^/proxy" : ""
        },
        "changeOrigin": true
    }
}
```

so `myreact.com/proxy/my/path` is redirected to `mybackend.com/my/path`

I think the error in your case is that you put the destination as a key for your proxy instead of path on your react server.

Comment: Hi, I've been trying this for a day now and it seems to not work at all. Using create-react-app but we've ejected. Adding a proxy object in package json with app server path endpoints to match, and outside services to hit as targets. The app still tries to hit a local route which does not exist... perhaps i'm missing a step that is not documented clearly anywhere? Alternatively, in the past I've used an express app with http-proxy to get around these CORS issues and it was pretty simple.

Answer (score 3):

For my case my api was deployed on AWS, I found that setting

```
"changeOrigin": true
```

was necessary (chrome & edge worked, firefox (62.0.3) complained "Invalid CORS request").

In the documentation of webpack http proxy they say this option:
(https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware)

> Tip: Set the option changeOrigin to true for name-based virtual hosted sites.

notes:

- running the api locally on same machine didn't require that for fire fox.
- firefox adds header "origin" which when I removed and resent the request worked.
- adding "changeOrigin" doesn't have side effects so I will be doing it from now on.

I'm not sure if it's a bug in firefox or what, anyway my final configuration was:

```
"proxy": {
  "/api": {
    "target": "<put ip address>",
    "changeOrigin" : true
  }
}
```

you should replace /api with the path of your api or rewrite the path as the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

You can proxy external API to localhost, change frontend origin (localhost:3000), target server, update token if needed and run following script in node js

```
const express = require('express');
const proxy = require('express-http-proxy');
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: 'localhost:3000',
    credentials: false
  })
);

app.use('/', proxy('https://www.targetserver.com/', {
  proxyReqPathResolver: function (req) {
    return req.url;
  },
  proxyReqOptDecorator: function (proxyReqOpts, srcReq) {
    proxyReqOpts.headers = {'Authorization': 'Replace with JWT'};
    return proxyReqOpts;
  }
}))

app.get('/*',function(req,res,next){
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});


app.listen(4000, () => console.log(`Server Listening on port ${4000}!`));
```

Use it in your fontend application like this (with axios or fetch) :

```
axios.get('http://localhost:4000/api/route).then(x => console.log(x));
```