# How to configure a proxy like in CRA without create-react-app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, proxy, expo, create-react-app

In a `create-react-app`, I can use `proxy` in `package.json` to configure a proxy automatically, as described in here https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/

This allow me to serv my app from a different port.

How can I do the same configuration without `create-react-app`?

It would be nice to have the same proxy to benefit the same configuration as in with create-react-app.

Comment: If you are using webpack then you can refer to this SO post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46393827/how-to-create-a-proxy-in-react-webpack-to-call-an-external-api

Answer (score 0):

You can create a file to run with node to act as your proxy. Like this:

**proxy.js**

```
const httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

const proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({
  secure: false,
  changeOrigin: true,
  target: 'https://someOriginURL.com',
  // could be an IP address target: 'https://XX.XX.XXX.XXX/',
}).listen(3500, () => console.log('Proxy running on port 3500'));

// Intercepts the request 
proxy.on('proxyReq', function(proxyReq, req, res, options) {
  console.log(req);
  // Set the headers of the intercepted request
  proxyReq.setHeader('Origin', 'https://yourorigin.com');
  // remove any headers you want 
  // proxyReq.removeHeader('authorization');

  res.oldWriteHead = res.writeHead;
  res.writeHead = function(statusCode, headers) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.oldWriteHead(statusCode, headers);
  }
});
```

to use this open a terminal and run:

```
node proxy.js
```

P.S.: Don't use this in production :D

Comment: Why do you prefer `http-proxy` to `http-proxy-middleware`, choosed by facebook and create-react-app ?

Comment: I haven't put much thoughts into this to be honest, since it is a development tool and it never gave me any problems regarding failed requests or anything... I started using this outside the react environment, so I didn't even know about http-proxy-middleware, but nice find, I'll take a look :D