# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON MERN App

Tags: reactjs, mern

I started a MERN stack app (ecommerce) and I just set up node and I am getting an error when trying to fetch the products from backend:

Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON

It points for some reason the error is in that fetch request in products.js

[piece of code that im getting an error in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6cl3.jpg)

and points to index.html

How to run frontend: yarn start in client folder

then run on backend yarn start in server folder

https://github.com/m4risol/Handbag-Hut
Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). See also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from the help centre.

Comment: If you intend to use the `proxy` config in `package.json`, you should probably have created your client-side app with [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/). Since you're using Webpack directly, you'll need to configure the [`devServer.proxy` option](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy) yourself

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a proxy in React/Webpack to call an external API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46393827/how-to-create-a-proxy-in-react-webpack-to-call-an-external-api)

Answer (score 0):

Your frontend runs on a different port, so you need to specify the full url of the backend endpoint

```js
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/bags") // or whatever the url of your backend is
```